# K8s OPA Gatekeeper doesn't block DELETE operation

Tags: kubernetes, open-policy-agent

I'm using K8s OPA to enforce policies.

From the official document debugging section (https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/debug), I created constraintTemplate as below.

```
apiVersion: templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1
kind: ConstraintTemplate
metadata:
  name: k8sdenyall
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: K8sDenyAll
  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package k8sdenyall

        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          msg := sprintf("REVIEW OBJECT: %v", [input.review])
        }
```

I also created the constraint below.

```
apiVersion: constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: K8sDenyAll
metadata:
  name: deny-all-namespaces
spec:
  match:
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: [""]
        kinds: ["Namespace"]
```

I thought that every operations regarding namespace would be denied. However, whereas `kubectl create ns test1` is denied successfully, `kubectl delete ns test2` isn't denied. Any ideas on why? I'm experiencing this issue not only with namespace, but with other k8s resources such as pods.

Comment: If you are making a constraint to exclude for particular name spaces then, use excludedNamespaces in the constraint instead. 
excludedNamespaces is a list of namespace names. If defined, a constraint will only apply to resources not in a listed namespace. Here is an [example](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/library/pod-security-policy/privileged-containers/samples/psp-privileged-container/constraint.yaml) and Refer this [blog](https://blog.container-solutions.com/enforcing-policies-with-gatekeeper-in-kubernetes) for Delete Operation Constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to [Enable Validation of Delete Operations](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/customize-admission/#enable-validation-of-delete-operations)?

> To enable Delete operations for the validation.gatekeeper.sh admission webhook, add "DELETE" to the list of operations in the gatekeeper-validating-webhook-configuration ValidatingWebhookConfiguration [..]

```yaml
operations:
  - CREATE
  - UPDATE
  - DELETE
```

> You can now check for deletes.